# was sent to an object that is not KVC-compliant for the "com" property

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I want to observe the value stored in UserDefaults.standard under the key: **com.apple.configuration.managed**, so I did this:

```
UserDefaults.standard.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "com.apple.configuration.managed", options: [.new, .old], context: nil)
```

I then implemented this:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

}
```

When I run the app observeValue... is never called when that default is changed, instead Xcode crashes with this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[
>   addObserver:
>   forKeyPath:@"com.apple.configuration.managed" options:1 context:0x0]
>   was sent to an object that is not KVC-compliant for the "com"
>   property.'

What's the right way of observing *com.apple.configuration.managed* in the UserDefaults.standard?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [Detect changes on NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202562/detect-changes-on-nsuserdefaults). The problem here is the dots in the key path, which that question doesn't address.

Comment: I guess this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14172860/728246 could make my question seem like a duplicate, I just didn't realize the "." was the cause of this error...

Comment: The root cause of the problem is the same, but `NSUserDefaults` is KVO-compliant whilst `NSDictionary` is not, so I don't think closing as a duplicate is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use KVC observing to observe properties of an object, and you can use KVC observing to observe the values that you assign to `UserDefaults`, but you cannot use KVC to observe a value where the value identifier contains periods, since this is used to describe a hierarchical keypath.

So, the exception message is correct, `UserDefaults` is not KVC compliant for the `com` property; what you have asked is to be notified when the `managed` property of the object referred to by the `configuration` property of the object referred to by the `apple` property of the object referred to by the `com` property of the `UserDefaults` object is modified.

So you can use KVC to be notified when "MyDefault" changes but not when "My.Default" changes.  If you can't change the name of your user default then you will need to observe the `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` `Notification`